# Import private interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Here's an example. All that `localforage` package exports is an instance of private `LocalForage` class. The respective typing has an interface of the same name, but it not exported, too.

Despite `LocalForage` interface it is not exported, TypeScript and IDE (WebStorm) seem to allow to import it from '@types/localforage'. But the type isn't applied.

This code has no linting problems and no import errors before `customForage.setDriver(...)` line:

```
import * as localForage from 'localforage';
import { LocalForage } from '@types/localforage';

var customForage: LocalForage = localForage;
customForage.setDriver('custom');
```

but results in error:

> Unresolved function or method setDriver()

While this code

```
import * as localForage from 'localforage';

/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/localforage/index.d.ts"/>

var customForage: LocalForage = localForage;
customForage.setDriver('custom');
```

successfully identifies `setDriver` method.

I was happy when `@types` finally arrived, and it is cumbersome to maintain  relative paths for `index.d.ts`.

Can this case be handled without `<reference path="../../... />` in files that use the interface?

The question is not limited to particular `localforage` package, but it is a good example for the problem.

Comment: And if you just remove the second import and the `/// <reference`?

Comment: there is no need to import `@type` directly in the code, it's resolved by name; and files from `"node_modules/@types/*"` are always included into the compile scope by default, even if node_modules are excluded in tsconfig.json. But `@types` feature is only supported since 2016.3, so you need to make sure to use the most recent WebStorm version

Comment: @lena Thanks. Indeed, 2016.3 doesn't have this problem and uses `@type` automatically. I guess the upgrade solves the issue, and this is normal behaviour for TS 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read and from my daily work with @types you should never need to import or reference @types. @types are automatically resolved by name. So for the module localforage the @types localforage are loaded.
A short summary was presented here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

I guess the problem when using webstorm or phpstrom might be, that you don't use the build in version of typescript and not the one you have installed for your project. Try to use the custom typescript version and load the one you have installed in node_modules. And make sure you use TypeScript 2.0

Comment: Thanks, It looks like this is true, previous IDE version has used TS 1.x.